# Please help: How to show that Aut(G) is a subgroup of Sym(G)

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group

I have to prove that if G is a group, Aut(G) is a subgroup of Sym(G), and later that the inner automorphisms group is a normal subgroup of Aut(G). I have time until tomorrow in the morning, but I have no idea what to do, please please please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a roadmap:

- $\operatorname{Aut}(G) \subseteq \operatorname{Sym}(G)$
- $id \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$
- $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \implies \phi^{-1} \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$

$$\phi^{-1}(xy)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(x')\phi(y'))=\phi^{-1}(\phi(x'y'))=x'y'=\phi^{-1}(x)\phi^{-1}(y)$$

- $\phi, \psi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) \implies \phi\circ\psi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$

Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am not able to show the last two points, I mean I know it makes sense but I don’t know how to prove it..

Comment: @TwentyTwo, I've added some details for the third point.

Comment: Thanks, and I’m really sorry but I’m not sure how this helps me :(